# How to create such count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create count for all rows in the fact table, which got:

Certain availability from dimension table (A) and belongs to one of 3 groups from another dimension table (AAA, ABA, ABB)

They either don't have STATUS from dim table of MT100 (or status is null) or they dont have ITEM_TYPE from fact table ARM1 - one of these consider them as counted so material can have MT100 status but if its not ITEM_TYPE ARM1 then its counted similarly if ITEM_TYPE = 'ARM1' but not in Status = 'MT100'

I came up with something like that

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FACT
 JOIN DimLocation DL
   ON DL.LOCATION_ID = FACT.CKEY_LOCATION_ID
 JOIN DimMaterial DE
   ON DE.MAT_CODE = FACT.CKEY_MATERIAL_ID
WHERE DL.AVAILABILITY = 'A' 
AND DE.MATERIAL_GROUP IN ('AAA', 'ABA', 'ABB')
AND DE.MATERIAL_STATUS <> 'MT100' OR DE.MATERIAL_STATUS IS NOT NULL OR FACT.ITEM_TYPE <> 'ARM1'
```

It looks that it goes way beyond normal count of all materials with criteria on Availability A and Material Group either AAA, ABA or ABB

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FACT
     JOIN DimLocation DL
       ON DL.LOCATION_ID = FACT.CKEY_LOCATION_ID
     JOIN DimMaterial DE
       ON DE.MAT_CODE = FACT.CKEY_MATERIAL_ID
    WHERE DL.AVAILABILITY = 'A' 
    AND DE.MATERIAL_GROUP IN ('AAA', 'ABA', 'ABB')
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you here. Also T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well.

Comment: Note that AND goes before OR. Consider some parentheses in your WHERE clause.